# Permutation of rows and columns of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Let $P$ be a permutation matrix. I would like to know when for a given matrix $A$, we have that

$PA = AP$

i.e. permuting the rows of $A$ and permuting the columns of $A$ leads to the same result.

More generally, I also wanted to know when for any permutation matrix $P'$ there exists a permutation matrix $P''$ so that

$P'A = A P''.$

I am looking forward to hints or references on this. Thank you.

Comment: The first equation that you're trying to solve is an example of a [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)

Comment: Can you clarify the givens in the second question?  I think you're saying *given* $A$, and *given* $P'$, can you find $P''$.  Is that right?

Comment: Or possibly *given* $A$, then *for all* $P'$ there exists $P''$.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first equation: we note, via the method described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), we rewrite this equation as
$$
PA = AP \iff \\
(I \otimes A) \operatorname{vec}(P) = 
(A \otimes I) \operatorname{vec}(P) \iff\\
(I \otimes A - A \otimes I)\operatorname{vec}(P)
$$
So, finding the matrices $P$ that satisfy the equation is the same as finding nullspace of the matrix $I \otimes A - A \otimes I$, where
$$
I \otimes A = \pmatrix{A&0\\0&A&\ddots\\&\ddots&\ddots&0\\&&0&A}\\
A \otimes I = 
\pmatrix{
a_{11}I & a_{21}I & \cdots & a_{1n}I\\
a_{21}I & a_{22}I \\
\vdots & & \ddots\\
a_{n1}I &&& a_{nn}I}
$$
where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: For the first question, I believe the OP was treating $A$ as given, and then asking for suitable permutation matrices $P$.